# Is it possible to simplify this SQL statement with multiple subqueries and JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I've spent a couple of days creating this rather complicated SQL statement, and it now gives me exactly what I want. Now I'm wondering if there is a better/simpler way to do it. Also MySQL wont let me CREATE VIEW on this statement

```
 SELECT name, a.user, liste, c.order, total_1kr, total_5kr, total_8kr, total_10kr, total_paid, differens, sbdato, spaid, sbreg, sfdato, sforbrug, sfreg
 FROM (SELECT t.user, t.paid AS spaid, t.dato AS sbdato, t.registrant AS sbreg FROM( 
    SELECT user,MAX(dato) AS maksdato
    FROM g_kiosk_f WHERE paid!=0
    GROUP BY user) AS x 
    JOIN g_kiosk_f AS t ON x.user =t.user
    AND x.maksdato = t.dato) AS a 
 JOIN (SELECT s.user, (s.1kr+(s.5kr)*5+(s.8kr)*8+(s.10kr)*10) AS sforbrug, s.dato AS sfdato, s.registrant AS sfreg FROM( 
    SELECT user,MAX(dato) AS maksdato
    FROM g_kiosk_f WHERE 1kr!=0 OR 5kr!=0 OR 8kr!=0 OR 10kr!=0
    GROUP BY user) AS y 
    JOIN g_kiosk_f AS s ON y.user=s.user
    AND y.maksdato=s.dato) AS b
 JOIN (SELECT t1.name, t2.user, t1.liste, t1.order, sum( t2.1kr ) AS total_1kr, sum( t2.5kr ) *5 AS total_5kr, sum( t2.8kr ) *8 AS total_8kr, sum( t2.10kr ) *10 AS total_10kr, sum( t2.paid ) AS total_paid, ( sum( t2.1kr ) + sum( t2.5kr ) *5 + sum( t2.8kr ) *8 + sum( t2.10kr ) *10 - sum( t2.paid )) AS differens
    FROM g_kiosk_users AS t1
    INNER JOIN g_kiosk_f AS t2 ON t1.nr = t2.user
    GROUP BY t2.user
    ORDER BY t1.name ASC) AS c
 ON a.user=b.user AND a.user=c.user
```

I have a table 'g_kiosk_f' containing id (user), date (dato), 5 kinds of transactions (1kr, 5kr, 8kr, 10kr, and paid) a cashier (registrant). Another table, 'g_kiosk_users', contains name and id (nr).
I want a result set showing

1. the date, registrant and amount of newest transaction where paid!=0
2. the date, registrant and amount of newest transaction where 1kr!=0, 5kr!=0, 8kr!=0 or 10kr!=0
3. the total difference of sum(1kr+5kr+8kr+10kr) and sum(paid)

So the result should look something like

```
Name | id | difference | newest paid date | newest paid registrant | newest paid amount | newest kr date | newest kr registrant | newest kr amount |
```

In the above I've included the numbers needed to do the difference calculation by hand, because it was needed at some point, but is now obsolete. Does any of this even make sense?

Comment: How does this part '`FROM g_kiosk_f WHERE 1kr!=0 OR 5kr!=0 OR 8kr!=0 OR 10kr!=0`' work?  Identifiers normally need to begin with a non-digit, but apparently you're able to get away with digits starting the identifiers.  Is that a MySQL extension?

Comment: Since MySQL does not support CTE (Common Table Expressions, aka 'WITH clauses'), there isn't an opportunity to use one for the (almost) repeated sub-query `FROM (SELECT user, MAX(dato) AS maksdato FROM g_kiosk_f GROUP BY user) AS x JOIN g_kiosk_f AS t ON x.user = t.user AND x.maksdato = t.dato) AS a`.  Because there are two slightly different filtering conditions (`WHERE paid != 0` and `WHERE 1kr != 0 OR 5kr != 0 OR 8kr != 0 OR 10kr != 0`), it isn't clear that you'd be able to use a CTE anyway. There probably isn't much you can do to improve that; it is just a big, messy query.

Comment: Could you please describe the higher level result you are trying to get?

Comment: @Himanshu I hope the addition above will help you grasp what I'm trying to do. I find it kind of difficult to explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it should be possible to rewrite you query like this:

```
SELECT t1.name AS name, a.user AS user, t1.liste, t1.order,
       SUM(t2.1kr) AS total_1kr, SUM(t2.5kr) * 5 AS total_5kr,
       SUM(t2.8kr) AS total_8kr, SUM(t2.10kr) * 5 AS total_10kr,
       SUM(52.paid) AS total_paid,
       SUM(t2.1kr + 5 * tt.5kr + 8 * t2.8kr + 10 * t2.10kr)
       -SUM(t2.paid) AS differens
       a.dato AS sbdato, a.paid AS spaid, a.registrant as sbreg,
       b.dato as sfdato,
       (b.1kr+(b.5kr)*5+(b.8kr)*8+(b.10kr)*10) AS sforbrug,
       b.registrant AS sfreg
FROM g_kiosk_f AS a
INNER JOIN (SELECT user, MAX(dato) FROM g_kiosk_f
            WHERE paid != 0
            GROUP BY user) AS a2
ON a.user = a2.user AND a.dato = a2.dato
INNER JOIN g_kiosk_f as b  ON b.user = a.user
INNER JOIN (SELECT user, MAX(dato) FROM g_kiosk_f
            WHERE  1kr!=0 OR 5kr!=0 OR 8kr!=0 OR 10kr!=0
            GROUP BY user) AS b2
ON b.user = b2.user AND b.dato = b2.dato
INNER JOIN g_kiosk_f as t2 ON t2.user = a.user
INNER JOIN g_kiosk_users as t1 ON t1.nr = t2.user
GROUP BY a.user
ORDER BY name ASC
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Though I am not sure this is more simple.

Comment: Maybe it is not much simpler, but hopefully it is more comprehensible and possible to make a view from.